# Google Map trouble in Android app

Tags: android, api, dictionary

I am creating some app with using of Google Map Api. I loaded google_play_service, got API_KEY, inserted it in Manifest.xml, but it did't work. What I did wrong? 
This is log

```
    9839-9839/com.example.miura.citytourbeta E/dalvikvm? Could not    find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
    9839-9839/com.example.miura.citytourbeta E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
    9839-9839/com.example.miura.citytourbeta E/dalvikvm? Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
    9839-9839/com.example.miura.citytourbeta E/AndroidRuntime?  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{}          
    : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class   fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
        Binary XML file line #6: Error  inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate       
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  
     Check that <meta- data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
     android:value="your API key"/> is in  the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below meta-data under Application in manifest file :

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the google_play_service.jar library in your project? Sometimes you need to import the google_play_service project and mark it as "is library". Do you still get the same error`?